# Does Felix Felicis "know" user's thought pattern to illuminate the path to success?

Tags: harry-potter

This potion makes sure "all your endeavors will succeed". So, does the potion follow the thought pattern of the potion user in order to determine what needs to be done in order to succeed?

E.g., Harry knew he needed to go to Hagrid in order to obtain Slughorn's memory. Does the user need to think of specific "end goal" in order for potion to work?

Comment: Using magic....

Comment: @Valorum, it would be lame if it's all there was to it, but it's a child's book we are talking about in a first place...

Comment: In the world of Harry Potter magic seems to be semi-sentient. Spells are cast that then act like they have a mind of their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that the magic in the Harry Potter series bends reality to the user.
So I would say that the spell, alters reality for the user either:

1) Making the decisions they make to be the correct ones

or

2) Altering their "thought patterns" to be the correct ones

Comment: So pretty much like potion GPS?...

Comment: I could see it working like that...
Go here, do this, do that, don't do this, don't do that, turn left, turn right, etc. That way, every thing you do succeeds.

Comment: Felix Felicis could be a distilled form of Arithmancy in that it generates a probability engine that can predict the best course of action based on the input of a human thought, then suggest that course of action to the user.